# TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__', tdd restful api

Tags: python, flask

How do I go about fixing this problem? I am not sure of what it means.

> File "/Users/kritikasingh/Desktop/Bucketlist/app/**init**.py", line
>   13, in create_app
>       app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name]) TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

This is the code where it says the problem is

```
def create_app(config_name):
    from app.models import Bucketlist
    app = FlaskAPI(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    db.init_app(app)
    @app.route('bucketlists/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def bucketlists():
        if request.method == "POST":
            name = str(request.data.get('name', ''))
            if name:
                bucketlist = Bucketlist(name=name)
                bucketlist.save()
                response = jsonify({
                    'id': bucketlist.id,
                    'name': bucketlist.name,
                    'date_created': bucketlist.date_created,
                    'date_modified': bucketlist.date_modified
                })
                response.status_code = 201
                return response
        else:
            #GET
            bucketlists = Bucketlist.get_all()
            results = []

            for bucketlist in bucketlists:
                obj = {
                    'id': bucketlist.id,
                    'name': bucketlist.name,
                    'date_created': bucketlist.date_created,
                    'date_modified': bucketlist.date_modified
                }
                results.append(obj)
            response = jsonify(results)
            response.status_code = 200
            return response
        return app
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message points to a problem with the config file.  Take a look at app_config[config_file]  you may a typo in there.  It looks like you want to use the method `get_item` and instead are looking for get_item as an attribute of something.

```
app_config = {...}
app_config.get_item("foo")
```

where you would want

```
app_config["foo"]
```

or something else along that line.  Search for the text `get_item`

Comment: so you are saying that I should change it to a list?

Comment: app_config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'testing': TestingConfig,
    'staging': StagingConfig,
    'production': ProductionConfig,
}

Comment: No.  The problem is in the config_name object.  So if you are passing in "development" take a look at DevelopmentConfig.  It could also be in the "config.py" file.  You will need to look at your config files and ensure they are properly done. Your error says it is in line 13.  Look there and see what is going on there.